# Java DB Stored Procedures

Tags: javadb

I need a step by step assistance on the technical aspects of the above.

Assuming I have written my Java stored procedure and compiled it, WHERE do I place the class file???

I will use either ij or my java program to create the stored procedure in the database but my question is: where will the class file be?

I am looking at this:

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure-Name(ProcedureParameters)ProcedureElements

Assuming I am executing the above from the ij command line tool, where will the class file with my stored procedures be?

Please provide me with a step by step technical assistance on creating stored procedures in Java DB. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html

Apparently you have to package the class in a jar file and then tell the db where to find it.

It's a long process, am now considering other options like mysql